# How to determine time quantum used by SCHED_NORMAL?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cfs

I'm trying to figure out what is possible value of time quantum that process scheduler use.

SCHED_NORMAL is used, which as I understand is CFS by default,

```
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 3000000
```

... and

```
kernel.sched_latency_ns = 24000000
```

Do I right understand that time quantum is somewhere in between of 3 and 24 ms? Can I figure out more exact value? Perhaps by calling gettimeofday in a loop or somehow else?